# couchdb replication

Tags: couchdb

From what I know, to avoid conflicts, couch will reject saving conflict document in single node,  and in other hand, couch will allow conflicts in the middle of replication.see [Conflict avoidance](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication_and_conflicts)

However, is it possible to configure couch and reject conflicts when replicate to remote server(i.e. push)?  This is very useful in the offline mode, in such case which we have a center repository.

This is useful because we have to resolve conflicts in the client and if auto merge fails we need involve end-users. This is more like git behavior and different with Amazon Dynamo(which encourages users to perform conflict resolution on read).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can let the conflicts happen in replication and still take care of them in the client.  CouchDB keeps both versions of the conflict, its just that the most recent one "wins".

The document with the conflict will have an additional attribute "_conflict" set to let you know that something needs to be resolved.

Read more on the [CouchDB online book's chapter on conflict management](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html)